# Writing to same pointer from two different threads in C with pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, random, pthreads, montecarlo

I am trying to Monte Carlo simulate an approximation of pi, by placing random points in a unit square, and seeing which points fall inside the unit circle. I am asked to do this with threads using `pthreads`. I am familiar with CUDA programming to some extent, so I am a bit familiar with some of the pitfalls. I seem to have a working program that runs faster than the sequential single-threaded program. However, I have two questions, that I believe pertains to my understanding of parallelizing the code.

1. At first I passed a single pointer to the variable `int* ptsInCircle` to both threads. I had a slight suspicion that this might not work, since both threads try to simultaneously write to the same block of memory. It did not work at all, and I had to implement it as below, using two separate pointers, and join the results at the end. Can someone explain to me why this is the case? I am not sure I understand. One thing I did notice, was that if I printed the value of ptsInCircle within a loop, it seemed as though the variable was correctly updated. Is this due to each thread having to spend more time each iteration, allowing the other thread to access the address without conflicting with each other?
2. I seem to, even using `int numOfPts = 1e8` as an argument to the function, have slight oscillations of the value between concurrent executions of the binary. Why is this?
3. Also any tips and points on the structure of my program, or parallelizing this case in particular are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "piApproxMultithreaded.h"

typedef struct placePtsArgStruct {
    unsigned int seed;
    double numOfPts;
    int* ptsInCircle;
    double unitCircleRadius;
} placePtsArgStruct;

void* placePts( void* placePtsArgStructInput ){
  placePtsArgStruct* args   =   ( placePtsArgStruct* )placePtsArgStructInput;

  unsigned int seed         =   args->seed              ;
  double numOfPts           =   args->numOfPts          ;
  int* ptsInCircle          =   args->ptsInCircle       ;
  double unitCircleRadius   =   args->unitCircleRadius  ;

  double xpos   =   0;
  double ypos   =   0;

  for ( int iteration = 0; iteration < numOfPts/2; iteration++ ){
    xpos = randomNumber(&seed);
    ypos = randomNumber(&seed);

    if ( sqrt( pow(xpos, 2) + pow(ypos, 2) ) <= unitCircleRadius ){
      (*ptsInCircle)++;
      //printf("%d\n", *ptsInCircle);
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}


void piApproxMultithreaded( int numOfPts ){
  unsigned int masterSeed   =   time(NULL) ;
  unsigned int firstSeed    =   masterSeed ;
  unsigned int secondSeed   =   masterSeed + 1 ;



  double unitCircleRadius   =   1.0        ;

  int* ptsInCircle_first = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *ptsInCircle_first = 0;
  int* ptsInCircle_second = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *ptsInCircle_second = 0;

  placePtsArgStruct placePtsArgStruct_firstPart   =  { firstSeed,  numOfPts, ptsInCircle_first,  unitCircleRadius };
  placePtsArgStruct placePtsArgStruct_secondPart  =  { secondSeed, numOfPts, ptsInCircle_second, unitCircleRadius };

  pthread_t firstPart;
  pthread_t secondPart;

  pthread_attr_t* attributes = NULL;
  pthread_create( &firstPart,  attributes, placePts, (void*)&placePtsArgStruct_firstPart  );
  pthread_create( &secondPart, attributes, placePts, (void*)&placePtsArgStruct_secondPart );

  void* status = NULL;
  pthread_join(firstPart,  status);
  pthread_join(secondPart, status);

  double ptsInCircle   =   (*ptsInCircle_first + *ptsInCircle_second);
  double myPiApprox    =   4.0*ptsInCircle/((double)numOfPts);

  printf("My approximation of pi = %g\n"  , myPiApprox                    );
  printf("Pi is actually = %g\n"          , M_PI                          );
  printf("Deviation is %g percent\n"      , fabs(1.0-myPiApprox/M_PI)*100 );
}
```

I am of course calling the program from a seperate file `main.c`:

```
#include "piApproxMultithreaded.h"
#include <pthread.h>

int main( void ){

  int numOfPts = 1e9;
  piApproxMultithreaded( numOfPts );

  return 0;
}
```

Lastly, I have the header file `piApproxMultithreaded.h`

```
#ifndef HAVE_PIAPPROX_H
#define HAVE_PIAPPROX_H

#include <pthread.h>

void piApproxMultithreaded( int numOfPts );

#endif
```

**EDIT:** I edited the program to take the comments by user @IanAbbot into consideration.

Comment: Is `int numOfPts_secondPart     =   numOfPts;` correct? Shouldn't it be initialized to `numOfPts - numOfPts_firstPart`?

Comment: The `rand_r` function is not being used in a thread-safe manner because both threads share the same `seed` variable that is not being updated in a thread-safe manner. It would be better to use a separate seed for each thread, with the seed initialized to a unique value for each thread. (The unique value could be as simple as adding a thread index number to the "master" seed value.) E.g. change the type of the `seed` member of `placePtsArgStruct` to `unsigned int`. Initialize the first one too `seed` and the second one to `seed + 1`.

Comment: Note that on some systems, `RAND_MAX` is only 32767 which is very small compared to the number of points you are sampling, which would result in lots of duplicate points.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks for your comments. With regards to your first comment: It is a good point, but i disagree since numOfPts is being used as the endpoint of the for loop. I think this way is the right one since the for loop of the second thread starts at a later point, but we still need to cover all of `numOfPts` iterations. I guess the naming here is poor and is what leads to some confusion.

Comment: @IanAbbott I edited my program to take your second point into consideration, and it seems a lot more stable. The concept of thread safety is confusing to me, and that might be the issue here, so thanks for bringing it to my attention.  About the last comment; this is for homework, and for some reason my teacher insists that we use rand() (well actually rand_r() due to thread safety). As far as i understand this method is quite old, and not a very good generator of pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I never noticed that. I assumed it was the number of points. By the way, why do you need a starting point and ending point when the points are random anyway?

Comment: @IanAbbott I guess I don't, good point :-) thanks!

Comment: Regarding `rand_r` thread safety, its parameter points to the working state (a single `unsigned int`) for the generator. But if both threads are using the same working state, there can be nasty effects such as the sequence getting reset to an earlier value unexpectedly.